# Datetime issue in SQL Server/SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I am trying to Load CSV file to DB using SSIS. The file format in csv for datetime is MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss when I loaded the CSV file to SQL Server it is  getting displayed as yyyy-dd-MM hh:mm:ss but I wanted in dd/MM/yyyy hh :mm:ss  in SQL Server. Kindly help me on this

Comment: Date and time data types don't have a format, they are binary values. If you want the data to be **displayed** in a specific format, then that is a job for your presentation layer, not the SQL layer. The problem has nothing to do with SSIS or SQL Server, but in what ever your application you have written is in, and that it needs to be set up to display dates in a specific (or user configurable) format.

Comment: To format the dates in a SELECT statement, take a look at these examples using the "FORMAT" function: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2655/format-sql-server-dates-with-format-function/

Comment: I strongly suggest *against* `FORMAT`, @Martin , it can severely impact the performance of a query. `CONVERT` with style codes would be considerably faster, and (again) formatting in the presentation layer will likely be even faster *and* importantly doesn't convert the value to a string based value; which can result in *very* different behaviour when dealing with ordering or even comparisons.

Comment: Other than the **format** of the dates after importing, is the **data** correct? For example, if the CSV had  the data "13/07/2021" does the SQL statement that retrieves this after import display "2021-07-13"? I'm trying to distinguish whether your problem is with display after import, as the comments above assume, or if it is with the actual import.

Comment: Hi Ross  yes the data is correct. I am trying to load the csv file with 6/1/22  12:20:29   i.e. 1st June 2022 data to SQL DB as   2022-01-06 12:20:29:000. Do you want me to convert the Datatime in SQL server or in Tableau because am connecting this DB to Tableau to  build the report

Comment: Hi Larnu,  so it is good to do the changes in Tableau not in sql or SSIS? Am i correct?

Answer (score 0):

As others have said a `date` has no format value in the database, and you should leave it as date when inserting it to the database, and the default format it will **show** you in result set is `yyyy-mm-dd`.

If you want that the results should be in different format, in your case that you want it in `dd/MM/yyyy hh:m:ss` use `format()` function as shown below, for other formats you can use `convert()`, but there's no British format with time using `convert()`, only if you concatenate the date and time:

```sql
select format([your date],'dd/MM/yyyy hh:m:ss')
```

Reference SQL-Server [format docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), [convert docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).